# extraction of metadata from gml file

Tags: gml, metadata, iso-19115

I am in the need to extract metadata in XML format from a gml file 
following the standard ISO 19115 
Can anyone suggest to me how to do that
Is there any open source for the same

Comment: Look at the ISO 19139 XML schemas (the XML encoding of ISO 19115 and ISO 19119), that should give you some guidance.